# how to prevent ckeditor load more than one content.css in the page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor

I am using several instances of CKEDITOR on a single page, my problem is that each editor loads a content.css file this makes the page slower

for example

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.config.height = 200;
CKEDITOR.config.width  = 'auto';

CKEDITOR.replace('textarearesultado{{$letras_iterator}}');
</script>

<script>
CKEDITOR.config.height = 200;
CKEDITOR.config.width  = 'auto';

CKEDITOR.replace('textareaevidencia{{$loop->index}}');
</script>
```

the result is

[image]

How could I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `replaceAll` method instead of `replace`

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#method-replaceAll

```
    <body>
    <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
    <textarea name="editor2"></textarea>
    <textarea name="editor3"></textarea>
    <script>
        // Replace all three <textarea> elements above with CKEditor instances.
        CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
    </script>
</body>
```